# GoDaddy subdomain forward issue with query string

Tags: subdomain, godaddy

I have a GoDaddy account for my domain. I am forwarding a subdomain to a different server but the relative path is not getting passed when the 301 forward is done.

Example:

- `test.example.com` -> `test.cloudapp.net`
- `test.example.com/?token=123` -> `test.cloudapp.net`  (not passing token in redirect request)

Comment: Tip... if you want full control over your redirects... do not use GoDaddy Forwarding or any other registrar. Attach the domain to some hosting and use the `.htaccess` method.

Comment: "the relative path is not getting passed" - Your example shows a query string (as your _title_ states) not a "relative path". Is the URL-path also not getting passed?

Comment: @SimonHayter  Even if you implement the redirects yourself, I don't think the query string is usually passed along.   With rewrite rules you have to use the `QSA` (query string append) flag to make that happen.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller should be able to using `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: _Aside:_ With an Apache (and Nginx) redirect, the query string is passed by default (without any additional flags or reference to the `QUERY_STRING` server variable). The `QSA` flag (Apache mod_rewrite) is only required if you are explicitly including a query string on the _substitution_ (target URL) and you want the query string from the request to also be _appended_ (ie. _merged_). @StephenOstermiller

Comment: How exactly was this "301 forward" implemented? I'm not able to test this directly myself, but I'd be very surprised if the _standard_ GoDaddy "301 forward" option purposefully removed the query string - as this would potentially break a lot of site's redirects and I've been unable to find any reports that this has been an issue?

Comment: Any progress on this? I woke up this morning to a pile of support requests from customers who are reporting a problem that boils down to this same thing -- that is, the query string is not being passed along during forwarding. I use temporary forwarding without masking and have been doing it for literally years without any problem. Sometime last night the behavior changed. In my case, I forward xyz.cc to mydomain.com/xyz and I really, really need the path and query parameters. xyz.cc/dir?x=1 used to go to mydomain.com/xyz/dir?x=1 and this morning it just goes to mydomain.com/xyz.